# .net api : trailing zeroes are truncated

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, deserialization, asp.net-apicontroller

I need the trailing zeroes to stay but when the 43.00 was deserialized in the api it just became 43.

Request payload in Chrome browser:

[image]

value in api controller:

[image]

Comment: It's not removing the trailing zeroes, it's converting it from a string to a number.

Comment: @phuzi how can we preserve the two trailing zeroes

Comment: I'd assume that a `UnitPrice` is an a numeric value, so keep it as a  number and so format it properly before displaying

Comment: Can we see the webApi Controller code? It would make this a lot easier for me.

Comment: @robjam there is no special code in the webapi controller just: ActionName([FromBody] parameter) ... and unitprice is decimal? on the api

Comment: Do you mean 'serialized'? Because in-memory a number does not have a visual representation.

Comment: @JssDWt I mean UnitPrice is being converted to decimal? type

Comment: Call `m.UnitPrice.ToString("#.00")` in your immediate window, and you will have your decimals back. Remember you are looking at the visual representation of the number in your IDE. You can change the visual representation when you serialize it, or show it to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code I would suggest to save the number as a string. Because otherwise the trailing zeroes will everytime be removed

Comment: @SimbaMeek: OP just told you how you can make them stay. Save them as a string instead of a numeric value. If you need a more detailed answer, post a code example so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

So, the default serializer for WebApi is JSON.Net, so you can change the serializer settings in the WebApiConfig.cs (in your web project in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs) in the Register(HttpConfiguration config) method.

```
var formatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Decimal;
```

That should be all you need to do to ensure that trailing decimals are preserved.

Comment: where do I place your code above. currently I have:

public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                
            );
        }
    }

Comment: Updated the answer for where the file is.

Comment: The FloatParseHandling is missing from the JsonSerializerSettings class

Comment: FloatParseHandling is missing from Newtonsoft.Json also

Answer (score 0):

An indirect solution is to configure the UnitPrice column in the database to have 2 decimal places. So saving 43 will be 43.00 in the database.

in PostgreSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD COLUMN "UnitPrice" numeric(50,2);
```

or if UnitPrice column is already existing in table:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN "UnitPrice" type numeric(50,2);
```